# How to force LINQ Sum() to return 0 while source collection is empty

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Basically when I do the following query, if no leads were matched the following query throws an exception. In that case I'd prefer to have the sum equalize 0 rather than an exception being thrown.
Would this be possible in the query itself - I mean rather than storing the query and checking `query.Any()` ?

```
double earnings = db.Leads.Where(l => l.Date.Day == date.Day
                && l.Date.Month == date.Month
                && l.Date.Year == date.Year
                && l.Property.Type == ProtectedPropertyType.Password
                && l.Property.PropertyId == PropertyId).Sum(l => l.Amount);
```

Comment: The `Where` wouldn't be returning `null` if it didn't find any records, it would return a list of zero items. What is the exception?

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: I get the exception:
The cast to value type 'Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Comment: @Stijn, no what you did still wouldn't have worked. The issue is the way the `SQL` is generated. `Amount` isn't actually `null`, it's really a problem surrounding how it handles zero results. Have a look at the answer that was provided.

Comment: **You shouldn't be using *double* for dollar amounts!** Even fractional dollar amounts. Never, ever, ever use double when an exact amount is intended. Your database columns should be `decimal`, your code should use `decimal`. Forget you ever knew of `float` and `double` in your programming career until the day someone tells you to use them, for statistics or star luminance or the results of a stochastic process or charge of an electron! Until then, **you're doing it wrong**.

Comment: I get this too, on an empty collection, but only on LINQ-To-Entities, not on LINQ-To-Objects. So, my unit test works fine, while on the real application this throws. Important to note!

Answer (score 448, accepted):

Try changing your query to this:

```
db.Leads.Where(l => l.Date.Day == date.Day
            && l.Date.Month == date.Month
            && l.Date.Year == date.Year
            && l.Property.Type == ProtectedPropertyType.Password
            && l.Property.PropertyId == PropertyId)
         .Select(l => l.Amount)
         .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
         .Sum();
```

This way, your query will only select the `Amount` field. If the collection is empty, it will return one element with the value of `0` and then the sum will be applied.

Comment: It surely does the trick, but wouldn't it select a list of Amount values first and `Sum` them on the server side, instead of on the database side? imo 2kay's solution is more optimal, at least more semantically correct.

Comment: @MaksimVI EF will generate the query upon the first materialization, when the `IQueryable<T>` chain stops (typically when you call `ToList`, `AsEnumerable`, etc.. and in this case `Sum`).  `Sum` is a known and handled method by the EF Queryable Provider and will generate the related SQL statement.

Comment: @SimonBelanger I stand corrected, the sum is made on DB side, but it's made on a subquery that selects Amounts first. Basically the query is `SELECT SUM(a.Amount) FROM (SELECT Amount FROM Leads WHERE ...) AS a` instead of just `SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Leads`. Also the subquery has an additional null check and a weird outer join with a single row table.

Comment: Not a significant performance difference and it's probably optimized, but i still think the other solution looks cleaner.

Comment: Be aware that `DefaultIfEmpty` is not supported by a number of LINQ providers so you would need to throw in a `ToList()` or something similar prior to using it in those cases so that it would be applied in the *LINQ to Objects* scenario.

Comment: For MySQL provider it will generate terrible SQL if Joins with multiple tables used. That can cause to stop correctly using indexes resulting in incorrect index usage or even full scan..! So I think from the performance view this approach should Not be used.

Answer (score 222):

I prefer to use another hack:

```
double earnings = db.Leads.Where(l => l.Date.Day == date.Day
                                      && l.Date.Month == date.Month
                                      && l.Date.Year == date.Year
                                      && l.Property.Type == ProtectedPropertyType.Password
                                      && l.Property.PropertyId == PropertyId)
                          .Sum(l => (double?) l.Amount) ?? 0;
```

Comment: When using Linq to SQL this generates a much shorter SQL code than the accepted answer

Comment: This is the correct answer. All others fail. First casting to nullable and then comparing the final result against null.

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer for Linq To EF. For me the generated SQL performs about 3.8 times better than DefaultIfEmpty.

Comment: This is MUCH FASTER.

Comment: i wouldn't call this a hack, as this is the exact use nullables are designed for, ie showing the difference between no data and default value

Comment: I tried both the DefaultIfEmpty() solution and this solution, actually in my case an (int?) cast.  This performed better as SQL Profiler showed approx 800 reads per query for this case, and 900 for the DefaultIfEmpty() case

Comment: But isn't this semantically wrong? I mean, why would you cast a non-nullable property to a nullable just to get past the empty list case? Wouldn't it read well if you opt for a empty list check along the way?

Comment: nb my own findings, using EF6 async extensions, this variant worked while the accepted answer did not when there were no matching rows in the query `var sum = query.SumAsync(x => (decimal?) x.Amount); return sum ?? 0`

Comment: It's a hack because, logically, a sum of non-nullable values should never be null. SQL SUM() _will return null_ for an empty set, and the query is equivalent to a literal translation, so you have to supply the missing logic yourself. This edge case shows why testing is important. Bonuses are it's faster than the `.DefaultIfEmpty()` answer and it works in more environments.

Comment: Same for me: The solution with DefaultIfEmpty does not work. Only this solution works (although I don't really understand why...)

Comment: This is obviously big flaw in Linq to SQL provider. I had several exceptions while trying to deal with the situation:
1. The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.
2. NotSupportedException: Unsupported overload used for query operator DefaultIfEmpty
3. InvalidOperationException: Could not format node ‘OptionalValue’ for execution as SQL.
Only this answer helped.
Explanation of all exceptions are here: https://coding.abel.nu/2012/08/null-sematics-in-linqs-sum/

Answer (score 9):

Try this instead, it's shorter:

```
db.Leads.Where(..).Aggregate(0, (i, lead) => i + lead.Amount);
```

Comment: Does this avoid the exception?

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: I have 15+ years of experience in C# programming, but didn't get this line of code from the first sight. This is real example of how not to write code.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Aggregate is probably one of the functional operators old-timers like me have their problems with, even after we figured out LINQ. I think it has to do with most other operators having their equivalent in SQL, so we can transfer knowledge. So is aggregate really less readable, or just unfamiliar? It's the 'right' operator here from a theoretical point of view. Sure, you could also cast to `Nullable<>`s and use `Sum`. My take on it is, man up and get used to the functional operators, the next generation will know and use them. A lot.

Answer (score 4):

That's win for me:

```
int Total = 0;
Total = (int)Db.Logins.Where(L => L.id == item.MyId).Sum(L => (int?)L.NumberOfLogins ?? 0);
```

In my LOGIN table, in field NUMBEROFLOGINS some values are NULL and others have an INT number. I sum here total NUMBEROFLOGINS of all users of one Corporation (Each Id).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

> double earnings = db.Leads.Where(l => l.ShouldBeIncluded).Sum(l =>
>   **(double?)** l.Amount) **?? 0**;

The query "**SELECT SUM([Amount])**" will return NULL for empty list.
But if you use LINQ it expects that the "**Sum(l => l.Amount)**" returns double and it doesn't allow you to use "**??**" operator to set 0 for empty collection.

In order to avoid this situation you need to make LINQ expect "**double?**". You can do it by casting "**(double?)l.Amount**".

It doesn't affect the query to SQL but it makes LINQ working for empty collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Leads.Where(l => l.Date.Day == date.Day
        && l.Date.Month == date.Month
        && l.Date.Year == date.Year
        && l.Property.Type == ProtectedPropertyType.Password
        && l.Property.PropertyId == PropertyId)
     .Select(l => l.Amount)
     .ToList()
     .Sum();
```

Comment: Please add some information to the answer about the code

Comment: I got error when I try without ToList(), since it returns nothing. But the ToList() will make the empty list and it is not giving any error when I do ToList().Sum().

Comment: You probably would not want to use `ToList` here if all you want is the sum. This will return the entire result set (just `Amount` for each record in this case) into memory and then `Sum()` that set. Much better to use another solution which does the calculation via SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to cast the value, as in the code below

```
(decimal?)(x.TicketDetails.Sum(y => y.Cost *y.Qty)) ?? 0
```

Comment: Strictly doesn't answer the question *Would this be possible in the query itself?* It just converts the result of the entire query. Other answers sufficiently cover how to do it correctly.