# Sum() Returns null in Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a big Entity Framework query that includes these lines.

```
var programs = from p in Repository.Query<Program>()
               where p.OfficeId == CurrentOffice.Id
               let totalCharges = p.ProgramBillings.Where(b => b.Amount > 0 && b.DeletedDate == null).Select(b => b.Amount).Sum()
               let totalCredits = p.ProgramBillings.Where(b => b.Amount < 0 && b.DeletedDate == null).Select(b => -b.Amount).Sum()
               let billingBalance = (totalCharges - totalCredits)
```

When I materialize the data, I get the following error:

> The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

If I change my query as follows (added in two type casts), the error goes away.

```
var programs = from p in Repository.Query<Program>()
               where p.OfficeId == CurrentOffice.Id
               let totalCharges = (decimal?)p.ProgramBillings.Where(b => b.Amount > 0 && b.DeletedDate == null).Select(b => b.Amount).Sum()
               let totalCredits = (decimal?)p.ProgramBillings.Where(b => b.Amount < 0 && b.DeletedDate == null).Select(b => -b.Amount).Sum()
               let billingBalance = (totalCharges - totalCredits)
```

I do not understand this. `ProgramBilling.Amount` is a non-nullable Decimal. If I hover over the `Sum()` call, Intellisense says it returns type Decimal. And yet additional tests confirmed that, in my second version, `totalCharges` and `totalCredits` are both set to null for those rows where `ProgramBillings` has no data.

Questions:

1. I understood `Sum()` returned 0 for an empty collection. Under what circumstances is this not true?
2. And if sometimes that is not true, then why when I hover over `Sum()`, Intellisense shows it returns type Decimal and not Decimal? It appears Intellisense had the same understanding that I had.

**EDIT:**

It would seem that an easy fix is to do something like `Sum() ?? 0m`. But that's illegal, giving me the error:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593371/how-to-force-linq-sum-to-return-0-while-source-collection-is-empty

Comment: @JonathanWood: "But I'm still confused about why this is necessary" read the title of the linked question again. It's necessary because the collection is empty. What would you expect the sum of an empty collection to be if not null? Clearly `0` doesn't cut it since `0` is a perfectly valid value for a sum.

Comment: @DavidTansey: I did see that, but it provides no clue about either of the questions I ask at the end of my question. This is the approach I will take, as needed. Just wanted to understand why.

Comment: Try what's in the accepted answer, after your `Select` add a `DefaultIfEmpty(0)` before the `Sum`. Now if you have an empty collection, you'll get `0` and the sum of 0 is, of course, 0.

Comment: @MattBurland: As I've indicated elsewhere, I would expect the sum of an empty collection to be 0. And, apparently, Intellisense, like me, thinks that Sum() will never return null. `Cleary 0 doesn't cut it since 0 is a perfectly valid value for a sum` Well, if 0 is a perfectly valid value for a sum, then why doesn't 0 cut it?

Comment: @JonathanWood: Because empty collections don't have sums. As Servy's answer explains, the semantics are different when you are using entity framework. Intellisense obviously isn't smart enough to be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I understood Sum() returned 0 for an empty collection. Under what circumstances is this not true?

When you're not using LINQ to objects, as is the case here.  Here you have a query provider that is translating this query into SQL.  The SQL operation has different semantics for its SUM operator.

> And if sometimes that is not true, then why when I hover over Sum(), Intellisense shows it returns type Decimal and not Decimal? It appears Intellisense had the same understanding that I had.

The C# LINQ SUM operator doesn't return a nullable value; it needs to have a non-null value, but the SQL SUM operator has different semantics, it returns `null` when summing an empty set, not `0`.  The fact that the `null` value is provided in a context where C# requires a non-null value is the entire reason everything is breaking.  If the C# LINQ SUM operator here returned a nullable value, then `null` could just be returned without any problems.

It is the differences between the C# operator and the SQL operator it is being used to represent that is causing this error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I assumed it had to do with the difference between C# and SQL semantics, but it seems like a shortcoming that the compiler assumes C# semantics here. If it did not, I could've simply used the coalescing operator to force a null return value to zero.

Comment: @JonathanWood LINQ cannot support the semantics of every single thing that could ever be queried anywhere, ever.  If it tried, there would be so much to it as to make it virtually unusable.  It needed to make certain decisions about what types of operations to support, what not to support, and what semantics should be supported.  It then becomes the responsibility of the query provider to map the operations that can be described in LINQ into whatever it is querying.  The reality of this situation is that everything won't map 1:1.

Comment: I understand that, but then in that case, it sort of calls for less strictly typed constructs it seems. Anyway, I had trouble finding an explanation of this. And the question got quite a bit of attention. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same issue in one of my EF queries when the collection is empty, one quick fix for this is to cast to nullable decimal :

```
var total = db.PaiementSet.Sum(o => (Decimal?)o.amount) ?? 0M;
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the .Sum add a DefaultIfEmpty(0.0M)