# LINQ Confusion with Sum and comparison

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am trying to determine what invoices still have a balance.  I am going thru the invoices via Entity Framework and attempting to calculate which ones have a subtotal greater than the amount of payments applied.

I have written the following 5 test cases

```
var test1 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Subtotal > 0);
var test2 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount) > 0);
var test3 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount) < 60);
var test4 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount) < x.Subtotal);
var test6 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount) == x.Subtotal);
var test7 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount) != x.Subtotal);
```

The results return this number of invoices

```
 test1: 392 
 test2: 216
 test3: 126
 test4: 0
 test6: 215
 test7: 177
```

Test 1 says that I have invoices with a subtotal greater than 0.

Tests 2 & 3 say that I have payments applied to the invoices, and that I can sum them correctly.

Tests 4 is where I get confused.  I can't get any records returned that compare a sum to a decimal in the table.    I've tried variations with parenthesis around everything, but to no avail.

Test 6 & 7 were suggested and those work, but what if the payments were less than the sum?  Or greater (which happened)?

How do I modify my LINQ to return the invoices that have a balance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that `_invoiceRepository` has records with balance?

Comment: test1 confirms that 392 of 392 invoices have a Subtotal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `test4` and `test5` are the same expression.

But in case this is a paste error, aren't the sum of payments equal to the subtotal? You are no taking into account cases where there is an equality.

```
var test6 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount) == x.Subtotal);
```

Comment: You are correct about **test4** and **test5**, was showing some alternatives.  **Test6** does indeed work! But why wouldn't a greater than or less than comparison work?  The case where there were no payments, is causing the **less than** to not return any values.

Comment: I have found a solution for the issue, but I'm not any less confused.   `var test5 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => ! x.Payments.Any() || x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount) < x.Subtotal).ToList();`

Comment: I thought you were looking for that expression: `var test5 = _invoiceRepository.Where(x => x.Subtotal >= x.Payments.Sum(y => y.Amount));` (note the less or equal sign)

Comment: Also, in most cases, Linq throws an exception with `Sum` when there are no elements, but I'm not sure if this is the case with linq to sql. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593371/how-to-force-linq-sum-to-return-0-while-source-collection-is-empty

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception if there are no elements in a **Sum**, but it seems that it will return null in that case.  Then it tries to do a comparison between **null** and **0** and the record is not included in the results.