# Sum fails on empty list

Tags: c#, linq

This is my list:

```
var MaxItemCountFromRegItems = RegisteredItems.MyRegisteredItems
                                              .Where(s => s.ItemID == _itemID)
                                              .Sum(s => s.Posted);`
```

It fails with error:

> Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Its clear error happens because collection is empty. I am wondering how to avoid it.

Comment: It must be something else that is `null`.

Comment: Check the answer in (How to force LINQ Sum() to return 0 while source collection is empty)(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593371/how-to-force-linq-sum-to-return-0-while-source-collection-is-empty)

Comment: The exception is *not* happening because the collection is empty. Is it possible that `MyRegisteredItems` is null?

Comment: @Andrew: Most likely you are correct. Do you have a suggestion how to avoid it?

Comment: You could use the null coalescing operator to ensure you have a non-null collection: `var myCollection = RegisteredItems.MyRegisteredItems ?? Enumerable.Empty<ClassRegisteredItems>(); myCollection.Where(...)`. Or if you have access to the code exposing this collection, you could ensure that `MyRegisteredItems` is never `null`.

Comment: You need to check the stack trace to see where the error is coming from.  My guess is that `RegisteredItems.MyRegisteredItems` and the exception is thrown from the `Where` extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (registeredItems.MyRegisteredItems != null)
{
    var maxItemCountFromRegItems = registeredItems.MyRegisteredItems
        .Where(s => s.ItemID == _itemID)
        .Sum(s => s.Posted);    
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Nonsense. This prevents NOTHING. What if list doesnt have item with _itemID? you'll get null, so will get the same error you suppose to avoid.

Answer (score 15):

Use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var MaxItemCountFromRegItems = RegisteredItems.MyRegisteredItems
                               .Where(s => s.ItemID == _itemID)
                               .Select(c=>c.Posted)
                               .DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
```

Comment: Tried that already but: 'IEnumerable<ClassRegisteredItems>' does not contain a definition for 'DefaultIfEmpty' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.DefaultIfEmpty<int>(IQueryable<int>, int)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>'

Comment: @Tagyoureit...You should select a column. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Your solution is valid but problem is that MyRegisteredItems is Null so i still receive same error.

Comment: @Tagyoureit...So you may want to use the null coalescing operator to ensure you have a non-null collection as *Andrew Whitaker* mentioned in comments: `var myCollection = RegisteredItems.MyRegisteredItems ?? Enumerable.Empty<ClassRegisteredItems>();`

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is:

```
if(RegisteredItems.MyRegisteredItems != null)
{

var SumOfItems = RegisteredItems.MyRegisteredItems
                               .Where(x => x.ItemID == _itemID)
                               .Select(o=>o.AmountField)
                               .DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
}
```