# Why LINQ Sum() throws "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Here I have

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary.'

```
var res = (from c in _context.Check
             join cp in _context.CheckProduct on c.Id equals cp.CheckId
             join p in _context.Product on cp.ProductId equals p.Id
             where c.Date.Date == date.Date
             select (cp.Quantity * Decimal.ToDouble(p.Price))).Sum();
```

But when I write this, the code is working:

```
var res = (from c in _context.Check
             join cp in _context.CheckProduct on c.Id equals cp.CheckId
             join p in _context.Product on cp.ProductId equals p.Id
             where c.Date.Date == date.Date
             select (cp.Quantity * Decimal.ToDouble(p.Price)));
          
double sum = 0;          
foreach(var el in res)
{
   sum += el;
}
```

Why Sum() is not working?

Comment: You need to pass parameter to `Sum()` the attribute you want to calculate. Something like this
`Sum(cp.Quantity * Decimal.ToDouble(p.Price)))`

Comment: This looks be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593371/how-to-force-linq-sum-to-return-0-while-source-collection-is-empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force LINQ Sum() to return 0 while source collection is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593371/how-to-force-linq-sum-to-return-0-while-source-collection-is-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
res = (from c in _context.Check
           join cp in _context.CheckProduct on c.Id equals cp.CheckId
           join p in _context.Product on cp.ProductId equals p.Id
           where c.Date.Date == date.Date
           select (cp.Quantity * Decimal.ToDouble(p.Price)))
          .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
          .Sum();
```

Looks like there is nothing to select, so in that case, default to 0.

In the second case, you try to iterate an empty enumerable so it won't even go into the for each clause.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I've got this "System.InvalidOperationException".

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `.ToList()` before `.Sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error when calling `Any` with an unsatisfied filter

```
public static bool IsBooking(this Address address)
    => address.ReferenceTypes.Any(referenceType 
        => referenceType == ReferenceType.Booking 
        && address.IsActive);
```

After first making sure that some elements exist, it is working - but it doesn't really make sense as now I'm calling `Any` twice

```
public static bool IsBooking(this Address address)
    => address.ReferenceTypes.Any()
        && address.ReferenceTypes.Any(referenceType
        => referenceType == ReferenceType.Booking
        && address.IsActive);
```